# How can i do a relationship with multiple entities?

Tags: python, flask

How can i link both entities with relationship with flask python?

for example i have this  entity, here i am trying to link with `user = relationship('User')`, so i am getting error relation of relationship (btw: Grant, User, Client are in differents files )

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Grant(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE')
    )
    user = relationship('User')
```

this is the error:

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Grant->grant, expression 'User' failed to locate a name ('User'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'model.Grant.Grant'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

note: those are my anothers entities:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True, index=True,
                         nullable=False)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return True
```

and this is the Client.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Client(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    client_id = db.Column(db.String(40), primary_key=True)
```

this is the error  `user = relationship('User')` please helpme

Comment: Did you define the User class first? It's not clear from your code snippet broken into 3 chunks.

Comment: @ggorlen they are in differents files

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Is the User being imported/defined first by whatever file is importing these modules? We're missing a [mcve].